# How to find fifth highest salary in a single query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

How to find fifth highest salary in a single query in SQL Server

Answer (score 23):

In SQL Server 2005 & 2008, create a ranked subselect query, then add a where clause where the rank = 5.

```
select
  *
from
(
  Select
    SalesOrderID, CustomerID, Row_Number() Over (Order By SalesOrderID) as RunningCount
  From
    Sales.SalesOrderHeader
  Where
    SalesOrderID > 10000
  Order By
    SalesOrderID 
) ranked
where 
  RunningCount = 5
```

Answer (score 4):

These work in SQL Server 2000

```
DECLARE @result int

SELECT TOP 5 @result = Salary FROM Employees ORDER BY Salary DESC
```

Syntax should be close.  I can't test it at the moment.

Or you could go with a subquery:

```
SELECT MIN(Salary) FROM (
    SELECT TOP 5 Salary FROM Employees ORDER BY Salary DESC
) AS TopFive
```

Again, not positive if the syntax is exactly right, but the approach works.

Comment: I want it in a single query using percent... how to get that?
select top 5 percent columnname
from tablename
order by desc

using this we get first 5 records, but I want only 5th one.

Comment: Both queries return a single number which is the 5th highest salary.

Have you tried them?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 1 salary
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP n salary
    FROM employee
    ORDER BY salary DESC) a
ORDER BY salary
where n > 1 -- (n is always greater than one)
```

You can find any number of highest salary using this query.

Answer (score 1):

To find the 5th higest salary from a database, the query is..

```
select MIN(esal) from (
    select top 5 esal from tbemp order by esal desc) as sal
```

its working check it out

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MIN(Salary) FROM (
    SELECT TOP 2 Salary FROM empa ORDER BY Salary DESC
) AS TopFive
```

It's working correctly, please use it.

Answer (score 1):

Can be Most easily solved by:

```
SELECT MIN(Salary) FROM (
SELECT Salary FROM empa ORDER BY Salary DESC limit 5
)TopFive
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try some thing like :

```
select salary
from Employees a
where 5=(select count(distinct salary)
         from Employees b
         where a.salary > b.salary)
order by salary desc
```

Comment: This approach will work, but has poor performance.  It is O(n^2), since for every employee in the outer query, the entire table must be scanned again.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it by using this query:

```
select top 1 salary 
from (select top 5 salary
      from tbl_Employee
      order by salary desc) as tbl 
order by salary asc
```

Answer (score 0):

The below query to gets the Highest salary after particular Employee name.

Just have a look into that!

```
SELECT TOP 1 salary FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT min(salary) salary
    FROM emp where salary > (select salary from emp where empname = 'John Hell') 
    ) a 
ORDER BY salary
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from employee2 e
where 2=(select count(distinct salary) from employee2
         where e.salary<=salary)
```

its working

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following one, it will help

```
SELECT MIN (Salary) AS Fifth_Highest FROM Employees WHERE Salary IN (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5 Salary FROM Employees ORDER BY Salary DESC)
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?