# How to find all of the fifth highest salaried employees in a single query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

How to find all of the fifth highest salaried employees in a single query in SQL Server

```
DECLARE @result bigint

SELECT TOP 5 @result = EmpID FROM Employees ORDER BY Salary DESC

SELECT @result
```

Above query gives me the exactly one record at the fifth highest position,
but I want `all` of the `fifth` highest salaried `EmpID's` in `Employees` table.

Above query is referenced from [How to find fifth highest salary in a single query in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358542/how-to-find-fifth-highest-salary-in-a-single-query-in-ms-sql-server)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In SQL Server 2005 and up, you can use one of the ranking functions to achieve this:

```
;WITH RankingEmployees AS
(
    SELECT 
       EmpID,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Salary DESC) 'SalaryRank'
    FROM dbo.Employees 
)
SELECT
   *
FROM
   RankingEmployees
WHERE
   SalaryRank = 5
```

Using `DENSE_RANK` will give all employees of the same salary the same rank, e.g. you'll get the fifth highest salary and all employees that have that salary.

Comment: Thanks again for this answer.. Btw, Where can I learn more of cte queries.. ?

Comment: Explore MSDN Books ONline - it's the complete SQL Server documentation - available to anyone, online, for free! See e.g. [Using Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) - or just Google for "CTE"

Answer (score 1):

This can be done it using the Subquery also. Below sql query does the same job

```
SELECT TOP 1 SALARY
FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5 SALARY
      FROM EMPLOYEES
      ORDER BY SALARY DESC
      ) RESULT
ORDER BY SALARY
```

You can find out more details about the same in my blog  [How to find nth highest salary using SQL query](http://code.askmein.com/how-to-find-nth-highest-salary-using-sql-query/)

Also it can be achieved through the CTE and using `DENSE_RANK()`

```
 WITH RESULT AS
(
    SELECT SALARY,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SALARY DESC) AS DENSERANK
    FROM EMPLOYEES
)
SELECT TOP 1 SALARY
FROM RESULT
WHERE DENSERANK = N
```

Just replace the N with the highest no of salary which you need to find.

Comment: two queries submitted by you will give completely different results. Also DENSE RANK query is duplicate (same as) of provided by @ marc and first query does not give result as intended by me.. I want all fifth highest employees, be it 1 or 10 all employees records which is the case in accepted answer..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM (Select * From Employee Order By salary Desc)
WHERE ROWNUM <= 5;
```

The inner query i.e. `Select * From Employee Order By salary Desc` will return all employees from the `Employee` table, sorted `DESCENDING` by the `Salary` column.

By using `rownum`, we can filter the first 5 records.

Ok I got your qns wrong.Well the following query will work.

Select * 
From 
       (Select ename, sal, 
       dense_rank() over(order by sal desc) as rank
       From emp)
where rank<5
order by rank;

Comment: Dud now my question raises 1st- Where is ROWNUM in the resultset ? For example fifth highest salary stands at 10k and there are 25 employees with 10k salary so will need all 25 records of those in this question..

Comment: Also there is not any internal keyword for ROWNUM in **MS SQL** as mentioned [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/f01b163a-7f91-4e05-873d-277c7a1b066e)

Comment: I got your question. The query would be Select * From (Select ename, sal, dense_rank() over(order by sal desc) as rank From emp) where rank<=5 order by rank;

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM EMPLOYEE AS EMP1
  WHERE 4 =
      (
       SELECT count(Distint(EMP2.SALARY)
         FROM EMPLOYEE AS EMP2
          WHERE EMP2.SALARY> EMP1.SALARY 
      )
```

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE @result bigint

SELECT TOP 5 @result = EmpID 
FROM Employees 
ORDER BY Salary DESC

SELECT @result
```

Comment: This will probably work to find the fifth highest `EmpId` only but (1) Isn't guaranteed (2) Isn't the requirement in the question anyway.