# how to get 5th maximum value from a table in sql?

Tags: sql

I have a table named `Products`, which has a column `Prices`. 
How to get 5th maximum value from that table?

I've found two methods:

**=1=**

```
select max(id) 
from EMP A 
where 5=( select count(distinct(id)) 
          From EMP  B 
          where B.ID>=A.ID )
```

**=2=**

```
SELECT * 
FROM Products Price1 
WHERE (4) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Price2.Price))
             FROM products Price2 
             WHERE Price2.Price > Price1.Price)
```

Comment: Is this for mysql or SQL server?  Why have you tagged both?  The answer is different for both.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358542/how-to-find-fifth-highest-salary-in-a-single-query-in-sql-server

Comment: I want to delete this question. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products
ORDER BY price DESC
LIMIT 5, 1
```

Answer (score 2):

why use so complex query:

Use this simple one- >

```
SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY price LIMIT 5, 1
```