# how to find third highest salary

Tags: sql

how to find out the third highest salary from table using sql query?
please give me just example by showing query

Comment: Show me the table fields: select MAX(salary) from employees;

Comment: Please add your table structure, example data, expected output and the query you are stuck with.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find fifth highest salary in a single query in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358542/how-to-find-fifth-highest-salary-in-a-single-query-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

```
select MIN(salary) from employes where salary in 
(select TOP 3 salary from employes order by salary desc)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTE with Row_Number to get the 3rd highest salary

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT EmpID,EmpName,EmpSalar,
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EmpSalary DESC)
    FROM dbo.Salary
)
SELECT EmpID,EmpName,EmpSalar
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 3
```

Comment: Ranking function `ROW_NUMBER` is the best option!

Comment: not a generic solution in my opinion..

Comment: @MilenPavlov, what you mean by saying it "isn't generic solution"?

Comment: No rdbms was specified so this will work in `SQL Server`, but not in `MySql` for example :)

Answer (score 0):

Using standard SQL, you can do:

```
select salary
from (select distinct salary
      from table t
     ) t
order by salary desc
offset 2
fetch next 1 row ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Max(salary)
from data t3
where t3.salary < 
    (
      select Max(t1.salary) 
      from data t1 
       where t1.salary < (select 
                          Max(t2.Salary) 
                          from data t2)
     )
```

[Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/37ea8/5)